# Android button setOnClickListener error in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to handle a button click in fragment in android but I am having error at `setOnClickListener`. The button is not in the fragment but in a custom listview. Here is the code and xml that I am using.

**programim_fragment_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listProgramim"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="370dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
         tools:listitem="@layout/list_programim">
```

**listProgramim.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/iconRemove" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment.java**:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programim_fragment_main, container, false);

         Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
           button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v)
                     {
                        // do something
                     } 
           });

    lstAdapter.insert(new ListClassProgramim("", 0), 0);

    return rootView;
}
```

what may cause this error?

Comment: is `listProgramim.xml` the layout you are using to fill up the ListView ? (list view items)

Comment: @blackbelt yes, thats true. only button items in a list row.

Comment: if you are using that listProgramim.xml as custom listview  then you have to write that code in adapterview

Comment: then you are looking for the correct object in the wrong place,

Comment: But I can fill the list it in this class. When I click button I want to remove one row. How can I handle this?

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is in the list item. You need to handle the setting of the clicklistener  in the lstAdapter when you inflate your list item layout.